# Designing a Linux-based system for transferability of ownership/admin rights without total trust

Tags: linux, security, kernel

Inspired by a [much more specific question](https://serverfault.com/questions/34730/if-i-change-the-root-password-on-a-linux-server-can-someone-still-access-root-if) on ServerFault.

We all have to trust a huge number of people for the security and integrity of the systems we use every day. Here I'm thinking of all the authors of all the code running on your server or PC, and everyone involved in designing and building the hardware. This is mitigated by reputation and, where source is available, peer review.

Someone else you might have to trust, who is mentioned far less often, is the person who previously had root on a system. Your predecessor as system administrator at work. Or for home users, that nice Linux-savvy friend who configured your system for you. The previous owner of your phone (can you really trust the Factory Reset button?)

You have to trust them because there are so many [ways to retain root](https://serverfault.com/questions/34730/if-i-change-the-root-password-on-a-linux-server-can-someone-still-access-root-if/38142#38142) despite the incoming admin's best efforts, and those are only the ones I could think of in a few minutes. Anyone who has ever had root on a system could have left all kinds of crazy backdoors, and your only real recourse under any Linux-based system I've seen is to reinstall your OS and all code that could ever run with any kind of privilege. Say, mount `/home` with `noexec` and reinstall everything else. Even that's not sufficient if any user whose data remains may ever gain privilege or influence a privileged user in sufficient detail (think shell aliases and other malicious configuration). Persistence of privilege is [not a new problem](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html).

**How would you design a Linux-based system on which the highest level of privileged access can provably be revoked without a total reinstall? Alternatively, what system like that already exists? Alternatively, why is the creation of such a system logically impossible?**

When I say Linux-based, I mean something that can run as much software that runs on Linux today as possible, with as few modifications to that software as possible. Physical access has traditionally meant game over because of things like keyloggers which can transmit, but suppose the hardware is sufficiently inspectable / tamper-evident to make ongoing access by that route sufficiently difficult, just because I (and the users of SO?) find the software aspects of this problem more interesting. :-) You might also assume the existence of a BIOS that can be provably reflashed known-good, or which can't be flashed at all.

I'm aware of the very basics of SELinux, and I don't think it's much help here, but I've never actually used it: feel free to explain how I'm wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with an automated total reinstall?  It's easier to verify that an install script doesn't contain any back doors.

Comment: Imagine a business where the admin of a large number of systems and services leaves. A reinstall is *very* disruptive in that situation. So usually it's not done, but that leads to the stories that occasionally surface about a disgruntled admin coming back to wreck things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you did say **design** :) My answer will contain references to stuff that you can use right now, but some of it is not yet stable enough for production. My answer will also contain allusions to stuff that would need to be written.

You can not accomplish this unless you (as user9876 pointed out) fully and completely trust the individual or company that did the initial installation. If you can't trust this, your problem is infinitely recursive.

I was very active in a new file system several years ago called [ext3cow](http://ext3cow.com), a copy on write version of ext3. Snapshots were cheap and 100% immutable, the port from Linux 2.4 to 2.6 broke and abandoned the ability to modify or delete files in the past.

Pound for pound, it was as efficient as ext3. Sure, that's nothing to write home about, but it was (and for a large part) still is the production standard FS.

Using that type of file system, assuming a snapshot was made of the pristine installation after all services had been installed and configured, it would be quite easy to diff an entire volume to see what changed and when.

At this point, after going through the diff, you can decide that nothing is interesting and just change the root password, or you can go inspect things that seem a little odd.

Now, for the stuff that has to be written if something interesting is found:

- Something that you can pipe the diff though that investigates each file. What you're going to see is a list of revisions per file, at which time they would have to be recursively compared. I.e. , present against former-present, former-present against past1, past1 against past2, etc , until you reach the original file or the point that it no longer exists. Doing this by hand would seriously suck. Also, you need to identify files that were never versioned to begin with.
- Something to inspect your currently running kernel. If someone has tainted VFS, none of this is going to work, CoW file systems use temporal inodes to access files in the past. I know a lot of enterprise customers who modify the kernel quite a bit, up to and including modules, VMM and VFS. This may not be such an easy task - comparing against 'pristine' may not be tenable since the old admin may have made *good* modifications to the kernel since it was installed.
- Databases are a special headache, since they change typically each second or more, including the user table. That's going to need to be checked manually, unless you come up with something that can check to be sure that nothing is strange, such a tool would be very specific to your setup. Classic UNIX 'root' is not your only concern here.

Now, consider the other computers on the network. How many of them are running an OS that is known to be easily exploited and bot infested? Even if your server is clean, what if this guy joins #foo on irc and starts an attack on your servers via your own LAN? Most people will click links that a co-worker sends, especially if its a juicy blog entry about the company .. social engineering is very easy if you're doing it from the inside.

In short, what you suggest is tenable, however I'm dubious that most companies could enforce best practices needed for it to work when needed. If the end result is that you find a [BOFH](http://www.theregister.co.uk/odds/bofh/) in your work force and need to can him, you had better of *contained* him throughout his employment.

I'll update this answer more as I continue to think about it. Its a very interesting topic. What I've posted so far are my own collected thoughts on the same.

**Edit:**

Yes, I know about virtual machines and checkpointing, a solution assuming that brings on a whole new level of recursion. Did the (now departed) admin have direct root access to the privileged domain or storage server? Probably, yes, which is why I'm not considering it for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Trusted Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Computing).  The general idea is that the BIOS loads the bootloader, then hashes it and sends that hash to a [special chip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module).  The bootloader then hashes the OS kernel, which in turn hashes all the kernel-mode drivers.  You can then [ask the chip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_computing#Remote_attestation) whether all the hashes were as expected.

**Assuming** you trust the person who originally installed and configured the system, this would enable you to prove that your OS hasn't had a rootkit installed by any of the later sysadmins.  You could then manually run a hash over all the files on the system (since there is no rootkit the values will be accurate) and compare these against a list provided by the original installer.  Any changed files will have to be checked carefully (e.g. /etc/passwd will have changed due to new users being legitimately added).

I have no idea how you'd handle patching such a system without breaking the chain of trust.

Also, note that your old sysadmin should be assumed to know any password typed into that system by any user, and to have unencrypted copies of any private key used on that system by any user.  So it's time to change all your passwords.

Comment: I thought someone might bring that up. :-) The flip side is, as that wikipedia page says, the system is secured *against* its owner as well. It's a nice concept, but that implementation of it seems far too keen on ongoing control by the system's creators (censorship, DRM, etc etc see wikipedia). I would prefer to trust those creators once only.

Comment: For monitoring of configuration changes as you describe I've found http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/ to be useful in the past.